# Different results with same input in request/response if input by one row or several rows in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure-ml

I created a classifier by trained SVM and PCA as well as normalization transformation. And use Request/Response Excel to test.[image]
And if I only input for one row, all the PCA would be "0"
[image]
but if I put more than one row together then the result would change and both behavior doesn't make sense.
[image]
I read some other questions below and I wonder if something wrong in "Normalization" calculating that it didn't count by referring "Applying transformation" but simply normalizing by data input.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bb800d7e-2fbf-4874-a525-aae9ace5df4f/azure-ml-webservice-same-sample-file-but-different-predictions?forum=MachineLearning

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21938a5a-ae9c-4559-82f0-95889b359206/normalization-and-predictive-web-service?forum=MachineLearning

Comment: It is because of the "random raises" that start the process.

Comment: @MárcioMocellin Would you mind explaining more on "random raises"? Thx!